# Change Java version in R studio

Tags: java, r, rstudio

R studio is giving me an error when trying to open an xlsx document saying `WARNING: Initial Java 12 release has broken JNI support and does NOT work. Use stable Java 11 (or watch for 12u if available).`
Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue and change to Java 11?

Comment: Did you try setting up JAVA_HOME to Java 11?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, it turns out that I just needed to set proper JAVA_HOME as indicated in the comments.

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="path to your java dir") #'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\...
library(rJava)
```